# "View More" button after every three bottom scroll using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, jquery-scrollable

I have tried a lot but can't add show more button automatically just after every three scroll down.

When I am going to bottom of my page it scrolls down infinite times. I have to stop it after three scrolls and want to add "view more" button after every three scrolls.

Comment: what have you done so far? maybe you can post your code?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >

<p>Try the scrollbar in div.</p>

In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'


<p>Try the scrollbar in div.</p>

In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'



<p>Try the scrollbar in div.</p>

In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'



<p>Try the scrollbar in div.</p>

In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
<br><br>
'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'

<p>Scrolled <span id="demo">0</span> times.</p>

<script>


var lastScrollTop = 0;
var x = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x += 1;
     if( x%3 == 0){
      var i=document.createElement('button');
      i.innerHTML="more";
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(i);
     }
   } 
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```